# While searching a particular item , it is not listing even though it is available?

Tags: magento-1.9, products, search

While searching for a particular product,the search function is not working properly.

[image]

When we search for an item, the specific item is not shown instead a list of items are shown in which the searched item will be available somewhere

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1)Check the product 'status' and 'visibility'.

2)Please refresh your cache.

3)Do reindexing of your site.

Comment: how can i reindex my site ?

Comment: @VarnaRaj, goto system > index management > select all > reindex the data

Comment: another method is from command prompt , go to your magento root directory then goto shell folder run below command ** php indexer.php --reindexall**

Answer (score 0):

1. Login `admin panel`
2. Go to `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes`
3. Search `name` in `attribute_code` and click on the row
4. In `Frontend Properties` set `Use in Quick Search` to `yes`
5. Then do `reindex` clear cache and check
6. Check your product `visibility` it should be `catalog,search`